# How can I change the screen blanking time on a Pi 5 and Bookworm?

Tags: pi-5

I've tried "xset s 60" to change the default 600 second time to 60 seconds (or any other number of seconds) without effect.

Comment: By default bookworm doesn't use the X11 server anymore, it uses [wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/), so most X oriented commands won't work (but I don't have an actual answer beyond that).

Comment: Realmen don't use windows  :)

Comment: @Seamus what about real women?

Comment: I *think* you can find a reference to [switching between wayland & X11 in the "official" docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#wayland). I *think* they are referring to config changes available through the `raspi-config` app - started from the CLI by entering `sudo raspi-config`. Apologies for being indefinite - all of my systems are "Lite", and all are still running 'bullseye'.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is done through a Screensaver; AFAIK this is not possible with Wayland which prevents other processes from controlling general display.

Comment: So it appears that Wayland does not offer a way to modify the 10 minute screen blanking if turned on. Is there a recommended screensaver that works with Wayland. The one I've used before on my Pi400 is xscreensaver.